# How to Rank and extract the data from a column of a dataframe based on priority and specific values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

first, `df1`:

```
data = {'Type':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        'Rank':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The frame look as follows:

```
   Type Rank
0   a   1
1   b   2
2   c   3
3   d   4
4   e   5
```

Second `df2`:

```
variants = {'Variants':['K|a&b|MOD||,K|d|LOW|,K|a&e|MOD||',
'J|c&d&a|MOD|,J|b&c&d|MOD||',
'H|b&c|HIGH|,H|b|HIGH||',
'H|b&c|HIGH||',
'K|d|LOW||,K|a&e|MOD|||,K|a&b|MOD||',
'-|d|LOW|,K|a&e|MOD||,K|a&b|MOD|||',]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(variants)
```

the `df2` look as follows:

```
    Variants
0   K|a&b|MOD||,K|d|LOW|,K|a&e|MOD||
1   J|c&d&a|MOD|,J|b&c&d|MOD||
2   H|b&c|HIGH|,H|b|HIGH||
3   H|b&c|HIGH||
4   K|d|LOW||,K|a&e|MOD|||,K|a&b|MOD||
5   -|d|LOW|,K|a&e|MOD||,K|a&b|MOD|||
```

I am trying to extract only high ranked `df1['Type']` in `df2['Variants']` by splitting `|`, `&` and `,`. I want to extract only one value from `Variants` which has considered as high rank from `df1['Type']`.

I used following code to generate the output:

```
d = df1.set_index('Type')['Rank'].to_dict()
df = (df2.assign(Extracted = df2['Variants'].str.split(','))
        .explode('Extracted')
        .assign(Ranked = lambda x: x['Extracted'].str.split('&|\|'))
        .explode('Ranked')
        .assign(Rank = lambda x: x['Ranked'].map(d))
        .sort_values('Rank')
        )
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()].sort_index()
```

The output was:

```
    Variants                            Extracted     Ranked    Rank
0   K|a&b|MOD||,K|d|LOW|,K|a&e|MOD||    K|a&b|MOD||     a       1.0
1   J|c&d&a|MOD|,J|b&c&d|MOD||          J|b&c&d|MOD||   a       1.0
2   H|b&c|HIGH|,H|b|HIGH||              H|b|HIGH||      b       2.0
3   H|b&c|HIGH||                        H|b&c|HIGH||    b       2.0
4   K|d|LOW||,K|a&e|MOD|||,K|a&b|MOD||  K|d|LOW||       a       1.0
5   -|d|LOW|,K|a&e|MOD||,K|a&b|MOD|||   K|a&b|MOD|||    a       1.0
```

But, it generated output incorrect for some rows. Here, 5th row of `df['Extracted']` should have `K|a&e|MOD|||` or `K|a&b|MOD||` but it has taken `K|d|LOW||`

The expected output was

```
    Variants                            Extracted     Ranked    Rank
0   K|a&b|MOD||,K|d|LOW|,K|a&e|MOD||    K|a&b|MOD||     a       1.0
1   J|c&d&a|MOD|,J|b&c&d|MOD||          J|b&c&d|MOD||   a       1.0
2   H|b&c|HIGH|,H|b|HIGH||              H|b|HIGH||      b       2.0
3   H|b&c|HIGH||                        H|b&c|HIGH||    b       2.0
4   K|d|LOW||,K|a&e|MOD|||,K|a&b|MOD||  K|a&e|MOD|||    a       1.0
5   -|d|LOW|,K|a&e|MOD||,K|a&b|MOD|||   K|a&b|MOD|||    a       1.0
```

Thanks. Any help appreciated

Comment: I tested and got `The expected output was` from solution above.

Comment: One thing - Is default index in original DataFrame? Maybe help `df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)` before solution.

Comment: I tried the same but 5th row is picking `K|d|LOW||`

Comment: hmmm, weird, for me working correct. What is `print (df)` before `df = df[~df.index.duplicated()].sort_index()` ?

Comment: its working on another system perfectly...!! strange

Comment: maybe some pandas version problem?

Comment: Ya.. it's the problem with the pandas version.. Thanks